# Are there things we can do in linear time that G-d cannot? (By His design and His design only. There is no limitation of Him unless He would plan it)

Tags: creation, golus-exile

In Chassidus there is a concept that G-d wanted a dwelling place in the lowest world, and humanity has a unique role of action in this world. However, we see in Torah that when G-d wants to intervene in the lowest world with miracles, He can do that. Of course G-d can do anything in general, but my question is after creating and exiling Israel to the lowest world, and the exile of the Shechinah to the lowest world, if there are any ways in which G-d so to speak locked aspects of Himself out, or aspects of His power out of the lowest world? Are there things now that only we can do, that He left to us to do, that even if He wanted to intervene after the fact, He no longer could because He planned it that way? In other words, from G-d's perspective, it might be something like, "not only do I want you to do this mission, but I trust you so much, and I've put so much of Myself into you down there with an illusion of separation between you and My essence, that I've made it so that the only way this mission can be completed is if you do it. I am literally locked out from doing it for you. I put Myself and the whole future in your hands. I locked out my ability to come in and save the day if you were to fail. It has all been given to you to do"? Or no?

And perhaps the exile of the Shechinah, if you exile part of your power to a state of separateness, or at least not as direct a connection to your essence, then from the perspective of human logic, say if you take an electrical circuit with a perfect connection at the essence, and separate it out through many contractions of the power, it will have less capability in certain respects at the end of the circuit than before. Now of course G-d is infinite so even if something is taken further away from His essence, would He just have infinitely more of it, so there would be no effect? Logically you can think about it from different ways, but I'm interested what the Rabbinic opinions are on this, not my own.

And the third aspect of this would be, is there any sense where maybe G-d can still intervene with miracles of nature, but something like a cell phone or a computer chip, only humans can make that now? Of course if G-d at the beginning wanted to make a computer chip, He could immediately, I am not implying different, but could that be an example of something locked in only for humans to be able to do now? Maybe because G-d is transcendent, the fact he made us in linear time has some sort of limiting capacity on what He can do during this stage? (Again, *it would only be by His design, I am not implying any limitation of G-d whatsoever except if He in His infinite wisdom intended it to be so only under specific circumstances. That is very important*). Or do no such concepts exist? Basically I'm not saying G-d is not the one with all the master keys. He is. But I am asking if He put some of the keys to the door of this level of reality inside of the door, with us, and then locked those from outside, not in every respect of course, as seen by His miracles in Torah, but in some, so that there are certain things at this stage He could not do here but we can?

Edit. There is also a concept in computer science that a program always results in things the programmer did not intend or expect. I would never apply this to G-d on my own, since it creates the danger of taking the question from being about something G-d intended to something He didn't, but I leave it here as a corollary for answers to work off of. Perhaps there are concepts that since G-dliness is part of our souls, that that G-dliness when put under the limitation of this world and linear time yields unique inventions ("creations" in some sense) than G-dliness that is not bounded by these limitations, or some other way of understanding the unexpected results of programming-analogy on a theological level that does not contradict with Hashem being all knowing and all powerful. But the question is interested in explanations from either and any (kosher) perspective.

Comment: This reminds me of the Ohr ha-Haim's approach (Gen. 6:5) to resolving the question of how to reconcile human free will with divine omniscience. In a nutshell (and this a gross over-simplification), God withholds knowledge from himself so that human agency can exist. There is a precursor for this in the Ralbag as well (Milḥamoth Adonai 3:4 and his commentary to Gen. 18:20–21).

Comment: @Deuteronomy Thanks a lot for posting that. Those answers really fit what I was wondering about great, and your comment is the only reply so far so I wouldnt have had any explanations if u didn't post. Ty. 

Do u know if anyone addresses, once He has so to speak withheld knowledge from Himself so that human agency can exist, if that now limits what He can do on this level of reality?

Comment: @Deuteronomy continued, If we presuppose that knowledge of how to do an action is required to do the action, then does this teaching imply that He can not do anything on this level of reality that humans can? Once humans discover how to do something, and it becomes part of their free choice to do it or not to (i.e., agency), then does He lose the ability to do it here at that same moment? Like maybe He can split the red sea because humans cant, but since humans can make a cell phone now He cant do that here? Or no? Maybe He can do it just things having the knowledge to do them, somehow?

Comment: @Deuteronomy Or maybe even before humans discover how to create a certain technology, it is still part of human agency in potentia, so Hashem cant make any type of so to speak technology here? Whereas miracles like parting the red sea, humans will nvr be able to do that (theoretically, unless Hashem wants it to be so), so maybe the Rabbis would derive that Hashem can still do all miracles here, but not create any technology or human type invention (so to speak)? Just thinking out loud, not implying this is the case.

Bc technically humans *can* part a sea, with tech, but *cant* with miracles

Comment: I have not seen any traditional commentator extrapolate from the idea any further. Sorry.

Comment: @Deuteronomy Thanks again. It's very interesting to contemplate if nothing else. Unless expressly taught otherwise, my default assumption will always be that one way or another, Hashem can always do anything. But I hope to learn more because I dont have the answers. And certainly within the nuances and specifics of concepts, like what you posted answering how humans can have agency, there could be explanations like those that apply within specific parameters, or are ways that Hashem planned everything so intricately and beautifully. I am still thinking about those answers today.